# Fire a method execution after x seconds in code behind - ASP.NET/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

After x seconds, after the page loads, I need to execute a method in the code behind. I cannot move this logic into JS.

Do I need to use delegates/events for this? Can anyone give me an example (preferably with a code snippet)??

Comment: Hey bob, why not accept some of your other questions answers? =)

Comment: Actually, look at his account.  It appears he's accepted lots of answers?

Comment: Could you give some more context here, e.g. what are you executing after X seconds?

Comment: It renders a popup for users to fill out a form. We need to show it only for users who've been long enough on the web page so that the information we collect is relevant. Currently, it happens on the server side on page load and it works great. Just need to add the delay functionality.

Comment: I updated my comment to add some detail based on your post.

Answer (score 3):

Put a counter in JS that measures the X seconds.  Once it's reached it's mark, have it send a message via AJAX back to the server, and the server executes the method.

That's about the only way to ensure that the counting of those seconds is accurate to *when the page finishes loading*.  If you don't care too much about accuracy, just have the server kick off the method x seconds after it sends the page.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "just have the server kick off the method x seconds after it sends the page."

Comment: Well, your web server sends off pages when clients make requests.  I wouldn't recommend it, but i've seen plenty of server-side apps that monitor when a page gets sent off by a request and then do something x seconds after.  This is klugy.  You're best bet is to use AJAX and fire a message back to the server..this will get you what i think you're after.

Comment: My website doesn't currently use AJAX and would not like to update a production website if it's absolutely not necessary. I don't need the timing to be accurate, would need to fire something off after 45seconds of page load.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get away from needing to update the production website.  The easiest, and most bullet proof solution would require a smidget of javascript to count the seconds when it needs to fire and then sending via AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML, really a group term for a collection of techniques) to the server to do that popup.  It sounds much more scarey from a production sense than it really is.

Comment: Exactly how do you plan to make *any* change without updating production code?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. That's not what I meant. I meant 'I would avoid updating a production website with AJAX code if it wasn't absolutely necessary'

Answer (score 2):

Your best solution is going to be to use javascript to either cause a postback, or to send an AJAX request to the server after the X seconds has elapsed.

Due to the page lifecycle of ASP.NET pages, you can't do it from the code-behind directly.  You can see this article for more information on the [ASP.NET Page Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#additional_page_life_cycle_considerations).

I would put a bit of javascript that uses the "[SetTimeout](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-settimeout-javascript/)" to trigger a JS method call that either does the Ajax request, or forces the postback, depending on what you are doing.

**Edit**

Based on the additional information you put in the comments to the post i would recommend a modified approach.  If all you are doing is launching another window, and you want to delay that logic.

Instead of directly calling the window.open or however you are doing it.  Simply put that code inside of the code that would be called using the "SetTimeout" method as I referred to earlier.  No need to involve the server-side at all.